# Groovy - confusion double vs float

Tags: groovy, double, precision, primitive-types

I'm using below two statements :-

```
double foo = 20.00
float bar = 20.00
println foo == bar
```

And

```
double foo = 20.01
float bar = 20.01
println foo == bar
```

It gives the output as :-

```
true 
false
```

Can anyone know what makes difference between these two statements?

Comment: Does my answer solve your doubt? Or is there anything else not clear yet? :)

Comment: @JoseIgnacioAcinPozo No, your answer is good and really helpful, I'm just waiting for some other input. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.1 part of 20.01 is infinite repeating in binary; [20.01 =](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/)

10100.00000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111...

floats are rounded (to nearest) to 24 significant bits; doubles are rounded to 53. That makes the float

10100.0000001010001111011

and the double

10100.000000101000111101011100001010001111010111000011

In decimal, those are

20.0100002288818359375 and

20.010000000000001563194018672220408916473388671875, respectively.

(You could see this directly using my [decimal to floating-point converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).)

Comment: This answer adds extra info regarding the low level differences between 20.01 represented with `float` and `double` but does not answer the question directly regarding why 20.00 gives a `true` output and 20.01 gives a `false` output.

Comment: @JoseIgnacioAcinPozo 20 is an integer so is represented exactly in any format. 20.01 is a floating-point value that is different depending on whether it is a float or double. (You don't mention that explicitly in your answer either.)

Comment: No hard feelings! I was only pointing out the real question purpose, you can always edit your answer. My answer says: "The rest of representations will always be slightly off, with small differences between doubles and floats ". I think that sentence is explicit enough about stating there will be a difference in value between floats and doubles. Especially given the fact one is represented with 32 bits and the other with 64 bits.

Answer (score 4):

`double` and `float` values don't have an exact internal representation for every value. The only decimal values that can be represented as an IEEE-754 binary floating-point for two decimal points are 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1. The rest of representations will always be slightly off, with small differences between doubles and floats creating this inequality behaviour.

This is not just valid for Groovy, but for Java as well.

For example:

```
double foo = 20.25
float bar = 20.25
println foo == bar
```

Output:

> true

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy Float aren't kept in the memory precisely. That is the main cause for the differences you have.

In Groovy the definition of the precision by the number of digits after the right side of the dot can be achieved by the following method signature:

> **public float trunc(int precision)**
>   precision - the number of decimal places to keep.

For more details please follow the [Class Float documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

It is more prefered to use **BigDecimal** class as a floating number when using the Groovy language.
The conversion from Number to String is much easier and there is the option to define the precision of the floating number **in the constructor.

> **BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale)**
>   Translates a BigInteger unscaled value and an int scale into a BigDecimal.

For more details please follow the [Java BigDecimal documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).  As the Groovy language is based on the Java language. More over the BigDecimal will represent the exact value of the number.